# Opencv contrib face library

Tags: python, macos, opencv, python-3.6, opencv-contrib

I am trying to use LBPHfacerecognizer in my python3.6 code.

```
recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

I am aware that face module is in opencv_contrib module. I even uninstalled openCV and installed again with contrib module. I compiled OpenCV with it and python still gives an error which is:

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Although in opencv/build/lib I have libopencv_face.dylib, it doesn't compile with python3 and opencv.

I tried everything I can think of but I am running out of ideas.

Any ideas?

edit: Python doesn't give an error when I am working under python3 environment anymore but I still have the same error when I try to run my code in the terminal.

What I am trying to run:

```
python3 main.py
```

Any ideas why I have this problem or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the first mistake of mine was after making cmake for few times, I didn't delete old cv2.so file and replace it with new cv2.so.

And it turned out that for working opencv_contrib face module, I have to put this new cv2.so file in the same file that my main.py exists. I don't know if this is the way how should be in the first place. I totally find out this coincidently by myself.

After this, my code worked without any error.

Answer (score 0):

> recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();

This makes error for me
[I tried out, just view the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGuSk.png)

Try out the code below, it may give you result.

> recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();